# How to check if file created using `open` is newly created?

Tags: linux, posix

When `open`ing a file with `O_CREAT` set, the file in question will be created *if it does not already exist*. I want special action to be taken only if the file is newly created. Is there a reliable way to check if this the case?

Currently I first attempt to open the file *without* `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL`. If this fails, I then attempt to open *with* both of these set, and on success perform the special action. However, this is not atomic and fails if the file comes into existence between the two `open` attempts.

Comment: What is the "special action" you need if the file was just created? Is it a problem if two processes do this at the same time and one process finds the newly created file before the "special action" is complete? Maybe create a new file with a different name that does not exist yet and try to rename the file using `renameat2()` with flag `RENAME_NOREPLACE`. If it is successful you have just created the file. If not you have to remove the new file.

Comment: You can first acquire a lock, and then see if the file exists or not, with all other processes that do the same also using the same lock first.

Comment: You could also try `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` *first*, and if it fails, the file already exists. (Though then you have a race where the file can be deleted before being opened)

Comment: The "special action" is zero-filling a very large (100GB+) file (to make sure it's reasonably contiguously allocated) and initialising a number of data structures within. If the file already exists, I trust the user to be passing a correctly initialised file (and to understand and accept the consequences of passing a sparse file that is written all over the place more or less randomly if that's what they choose to do) and skip that step. This question was mostly out of curiosity - in practice two processes *should* not be trying to open / create the same file at once anyway.

Comment: The suggestions in these comments could work as answers if you want to post them.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this.

```cpp
int open_or_create(char const* path, int flags, bool* was_created) {
    int fd;
    while (true) {
        // Try to open existing file.
        fd = open(path, flags & ~(O_CREAT | O_EXCL));
        // If this succeeds, of fails for any reason other than that
        // it doesn't exist, return.
        if (fd != -1 || errno != ENOENT) {
            if (fd != -1) {
                *was_created = false;
            }
            return fd;
        }
        // Otherwise, it failed because the file doesn't exist.
        // Try to create it.
        fd = open(path, flags | O_CREAT | O_EXCL);
        // If this succeeds or fails for any reason other than that
        // the file already exists, return.
        if (fd != -1 || errno != EEXIST) {
            if (fd != -1) {
                *was_created = true;
            }
            return fd;
        }
        // Otherwise, it failed because the file already exists. Retry.
    }
}
```

The two cases can be freely swapped if it's more likely that the file doesn't exist than that it already exists.

There is a theoretical failure mode where another process repeatedly creates and deletes the file just before we try create it and just before we try to open it respectively. In practice this is extremely unlikely to be an issue.

Comment: I would add a counter to the loop (i.e. make it a `for`) so that if it fails some number of times repeatedly, we break out and return an error. In the common case, this shouldn't repeat even once. If we have looped many times unsuccessfully, something is probably broken.